# Adicionar item com array diferente

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tenho a seguinte array()

```
Array
(
    [nome_responsavel] => 
    [telefone] => 
    [email] => 
    [dependentenome] => Array
        (
            [0] => qqq
            [1] => qqq
            [2] => qqqq
        )

    [dependentedata] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-01-18
            [1] => 2017-01-04
            [2] => 2017-01-06
        )

)
```

Preciso fazer um insert da seguinte forma

```
INSERT INTO tabela (nome, data) VALUES ('nome', 'data');
```

Como posso fazer isso, sendo que tenho uma array com duas colunas diferentes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria isso que você precisa?

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (nome, data) VALUES ';
for($i = 0; $i < count($array['dependentenome']); $i++){
     $sqlValues[] = "('{$array['dependentenome'][$i]}', '{$array['dependentedata'][$i]}')";
}
$sql .= implode(', ', $sqlValues) . ';';

echo $sql;
```

Resultado:

> INSERT INTO tabela (nome, data) VALUES ('qqq', '2017-01-18'), ('qqqq', '2017-01-04'), ('qqqqq', '2017-01-06');

Comment: Exatamente isso, muito thanks!